# MySQL Index Fragmentation

Tags: mysql, index, fragmentation

Is there any way to find out the fragmentation of indexes in MySQL ?

If such an output can be obtained, it would be helpful to identify which all indexes need to be rebuilt.

I'm using MySQL 5.1 on Windows Server 2008

Can somebody please help me.

Comment: Are you using InnoDB, MyISAM, or a mixture of both ???

Comment: If you are using InnoDB, do you have innodb_file_per_table configured ???

Comment: I'm using InnoDB with "innodb_file_per_table"

Answer (score 2):

For InnoDB tables, this is both possible and redundant.
It is possible using Percona Server's `INNODB_INDEX_STATS` table in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. This table shows you the number of pages per index in an InnoDB tables.

Well, apparently InnoDB manages its own pages very well. Upon purging of data it merges back its index nodes. I have done multiple tests to verify that an `OPTIMIZE TABLE` -- a complete rebuild of the table -- does not actually improve on index fragmentation.

Please see [my post on the subject](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/how-often-should-you-use-optimize-table-followup).

By the way, I believe MySQL **5.6** has a similar table built-in.

With regard MyISAM tables, I'm unaware that there's any way of looking at the fragmentation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But as far as i know, the Percona server is available for Linux systems only.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I should have noticed that.

Comment: The number of index blocks can be misleading since it usually includes pre-allocated, but empty, blocks.

Comment: Also rebuilding a table can increase index performance by magnitudes, innodb doens't do that on it's own. (8.0.13)